# how do I sum up this python Dictionary and get the average?

Tags: python-3.x

d =[{'C': 0, 'B': 2.0, 'A': 7.0, 'D': 3.0}, {'C': 2.0, 'B': 0, 'A': 5.0, 'D': 5.0}, {'C': 7.0, 'B': 5.0, 'A': 0, 'D': 10.0}, {'C': 3.0, 'B': 5.0, 'A': 10.0, 'D': 0}]

how do I sum up this python Dictionary and get the average ?...

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> d
[{'D': 3.0, 'A': 7.0, 'C': 0, 'B': 2.0}, {'D': 5.0, 'A': 5.0, 'C': 2.0, 'B': 0}, {'D': 10.0, 'A': 0, 'C': 7.0, 'B': 5.0}, {'D': 0, 'A': 10.0, 'C': 3.0, 'B': 5.0}]
>>> l = len(d)
>>> s = reduce(lambda x,y: {z:x[z]+y[z] for z in ['A','B','C','D']}, d)
>>> s = {x:s[x]/l for x in s}
>>> s
{'D': 4.5, 'A': 5.5, 'C': 3.0, 'B': 3.0}
>>>
```

Comment: Nice solution to accumulate the values!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the averages of the `'C'` field. Just change the `'C'` to the desired fields for the other averages.

```
cAVG = sum(map(lambda item: item['C'], d))/len(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont explicitly stated how you want to average the values.

You can get all the values with this genexp:

```
>>> [v for subdict in d for v in subdict.values()]
[2.0, 0, 7.0, 3.0, 0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 7.0, 0, 10.0, 5.0, 3.0, 10.0, 0]
```

To average the sums of dictionaries by number of dictionaries:

```
>>> sum(v for subdict in d for v in subdict.values())/len(d)
16.0
```

To average them by subdictionary:

```
>>> [sum(subdict.values())/len(subdict) for subdict in d]
[3.0, 3.0, 5.5, 4.5]
```

If you just want the average 'A':

```
>>> sum(v for subdict in d for k, v in subdict.items() if k == 'A')/len(d)
5.5
```